# Trying to deploy Laravel app with tailwindcss on frontend. But, when i execute npm run dev i get an error

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css, postcss

When npm run dev is being executed in cmd, i get an error saying that i need postcss v8 and i already have postcss v8.3. Is it possible that tailwind requires exact version that is 8 even tho newer versions are being released. Everything is set up "right", like its said in their documentation. This is the error i get, any suggestions are welcome.

> laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 dev C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example
> npm run development

> laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 development C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                       1:37:09 PM
error  in ./resources/css/app.css

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
at Processor.normalize (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:153:15)
at new Processor (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
at postcss (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:140:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:208:9
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

error  in ./resources/css/app.css

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
at Processor.normalize (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:153:15)
at new Processor (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
at postcss (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:140:12

@ ./resources/css/app.css 2:14-142

```
 Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
```

/js/app.js  597 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
at Processor.normalize (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:153:15)
at new Processor (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
at postcss (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:140:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:208:9
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
@ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
at Processor.normalize (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:153:15)
at new Processor (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
at postcss (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-movies-example\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:140:12
@ ./resources/css/app.css 2:14-142
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-27T11_37_16_434Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the laravel-movies-example@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-27T11_37_16_514Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `package.json` with a `package.json` from a clean project.

`package.json` from a clean project:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
    }
}
```